# Split multiple bytes according to bit masks

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation, mask, bitmask

I'm trying to split bytes according to bit masks.

Consider these two bytes (1000 in binary as short int):

`11101000`

`00000011`

and these three masks:

`00000011`

`11111111`

`00111111`

What I want to do is to split the two original bytes in three bytes according to the masks provided.

The result should be:

`00000000` for the first byte

`11111010` for the second (original byte 1 and 2 are merged because of the mask)

`00000000` for the third (remaining bits are filled with zeros)

What is the easiest way to do it in Java or C?

Comment: You need to read about the bitwise operators (`&` and `|`). But it is pretty unclear whicch byte should be masked with what.

Comment: I know how to use bitwise operators. What I'm trying to do in the easiest way is to merge a part of the first byte with a part of the second byte in the right order because of the mask. I know this is simple example but it has to work whatever is the mask provided, so I need some bit shifting to adjust the right order.

Comment: What does the mask mean?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution, or only if masks has contiguous ones, or just contiguous ones in the end? Are you supposed to do with and/or/xor/shifts, or you can use ops like `popcount` and `pdep`?

Comment: @corir146 you need to show us some examples.

Comment: Edit: The masks always have contiguous ones in the end

Comment: Do you have a working solution? Then we can try to make an easier way. Your example does not make sense to me.

Comment: I don't have a working solution. What don't you understand? How can I help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C if using x86, this is a single `pdep` operation.

```c
#include <immintrin.h>

int msk(int num) {
    int src =  0b0000001111101000;
    int mask = 0b001111111111111100000011;

    int result = _pdep_u32(src,mask);

    int expected_result = 0b000000001111101000000000;

    if (result == expected_result) {
        return 1; // returns this
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

See [_pdep_u32 in Intel Intrinsic Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_pdep_u32&ig_expand=5207).

https://godbolt.org/z/b6E6M8518

---

If your inputs/output are arrays of exactly 4 bytes, you can just `memcpy` from array to `int` and back.

If you're targeting not only x86, targeting older x86 that don't have BMI2, or want Java solution, you'll have to implement this algorithm from PDEP documentation:

```
tmp := a
dst := 0
m := 0
k := 0
DO WHILE m < 32
    IF mask[m] == 1
        dst[m] := tmp[k]
        k := k + 1
    FI
    m := m + 1
OD
```

`dst[m]` or `tmp[k]` can be accomplished with array indexing and bit shifts, specifically `dst[m] := tmp[k]` is (assuming 8-bit byte):

```c
unsigned char bit = (dst[k/8] >> (k%8)) & 1;
dst[m/8] |= bit << (m%8)
```

Note that the direct implementation is not only a bit more complex, it is also less efficient, as `pdep` is a single CPU instruction. But I'm not sure if Java exposes it, and if not, then if using JNI to call C implementation is worth doing.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I meant. Do you know if there is an equivalent function in Java? I need to write this function in both C and Java. My inputs are array of bytes (array of 4 bytes instead of int), do you know if there is something that works with arrays?

Comment: @corir146, in `C` you can `memcpy` array content to `int`, and then `memcpy` the resulting `int` to an array. For Java probably there's no easy way, and you'll have to implement the algorithm using a loop with two counters and copying by a single bit. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna implement this algorithm so that can be used in both C and Java with arrays of bytes.